# iPhone app rejected for not running on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

My app has been rejected because apparently its design slightly breaks on an iPad (a label overlaps something else due to the weird resolution)...
After clarifying that the app has only 'iPhone' selected in XCode (rather than Universal) I still received the following message.

> Thank you for your response and your effort to resolve this issue.
>   Even if your app was developed specifically for iPhone, users should
>   still be able to use your app on iPad.

I don't understand the rational here, since:

1. This is an app update, the currently live-published version has the same *issue* on iPad.. but
2. It can't be downloaded on iPad anyway (doesn't appear in the store - probably because its not specified as a 'Universal' app)

The smallest physical iPhone that the app will run on (by virtue of it's target iOS version) is the iPhone 5, which it runs perfectly on.

How can I resolve this issue without doing a heap of work to support devices which we don't support and which can't get the app anyway?

Comment: iPads can run iPhone only apps, they run in a letterboxed view that is the aspect ratio of an iPhone 4S

Comment: I know they *can* run iPhone apps, and I can see their 'issue' when I run it on an iPad from XCode - but how is this relevant when real users can't ever get there?

Comment: @user3109468 You can download iPhone-only apps on the iPad from the app store. They will run as dan mentioned above.

Comment: While I can't seem to find iPhone apps on the new iOS 11 app store, on the iOS 10 app store, you can see iPhone only apps in the search results if you select them and people are still running iOS 10.  Some devices will never get iOS 11.  You can argue all you want, but at the end of the day only Apple can approve your app, so you can either spend time here complaining or spend time addressing the issue.

Comment: Oh damn. I found the filter option to show iPhone apps in iPad. Well that sucks for developers.